# How to generate a distribution of k shots on n enemies

Tags: java, math

I am developing a space combat game in Java as part of an ongoing effort to learn the language. In a battle, I have *k* ships firing their guns at a fleet of *n* of their nefarious enemies. Depending on how many of their enemies get hit by how many of the shots, (each ship fires one shot which hits one enemy), some will be damaged and some destroyed. I want to figure out how many enemies were hit once, how many were hit twice and so on, so that at the end I have a table that looks something like this, for 100 shots fired:

```
Number of hits | Number of occurences | Total shots
----------------------------------------------------
       1       |        30            |      30
       2       |        12            |      24
       3       |         4            |      12
       4       |         7            |      28
       5       |         1            |       5
```

Obviously, I can brute force this for small numbers of shots and enemies by randomly placing each shot on an enemy and then counting how many times each got shot at the end. This method, however, will be very impractical if I've got three million intrepid heroes firing on a swarm of ten million enemies.

Ideally, what I'd like is a way to generate a distribution of how many enemies are likely to be hit by exactly some number of shots. I could then use a random number generator to pick a point on that distribution, and then repeat this process, increasing the number of hits each time, until approximately all shots are accounted for. Is there a general statistical distribution / way of estimating approximately how many enemies get hit by how many shots?

I've been trying to work out something from the birthday problem to figure out the probability of how many birthdays are shared by exactly some number of people, but have not made any significant progress.

I will be implementing this in Java.

**EDIT:** I found a simplification of this that may be easier to solve: what's the distribution of probabilities that *n* enemies are not hit at all? I.e. whats the probability that zero are not hit, one is not hit, two are not hit, etc.

It's a similar problem, (ok, the same problem but with a simplification), but seems like it might be easier to solve, and would let me generate the full distribution in a couple of iterations.

Comment: Are you sure you're not over-complicating things? If you sample from a uniform distribution using something like `Random.nextInt` then, on average, each enemy will be hit the same number of times. Or are you looking for a more adaptive algorithm - say skewing the distribution towards enemies that have not yet been shot?

Comment: @BoristheSpider He wants more than the average number of shots---he wants the distribution of the number of shots.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That will be the same (in expectation) as the distribution sampled from - if you sample for a uniform then the distribution will be uniform...

Comment: @BoristheSpider So the number of ships hit once == number hit twice == ...? Highly unlikely.

Comment: Assume that only one enemy is hit 5 times. Does it matter to your application if enemy number 73 is hit 5 times, or enemy number 10234?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see what you mean, I was just saying that the number of hits (in expectation) on each ship is given by the distribution that the ships are sampled from. The actual distribution cannot be known unless it is worked out explicitly. So if the OP wants to average two hits per ship then firing twice as many shots as ships would do it. There is not way of knowing a priori what the actual distribution would be any more than it is possible to know the outcome of a coin flip a priori - it needs to be _observed_.

Comment: @Marko durron597 Doesn't matter which enemy is hit five times, just the number of enemies that were hit five times.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The distribution *is* known in advance. Just like it is known in advance that half the flips will be heads. OP is not asking about any particular coin flip.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm assuming a known number of hits, so the average would just be *n/k*. I'd like to know, for example, approximately how many are hit exactly twice, which should be some sort of distribution. If I can create a CDF for number of ships hit twice, I can invert the CDF and generate a random number to randomize the number of ships hit twice in a manner which approximates what would happen if I brute forced the simulation. I'm trying to figure out what the CDF looks like. (Or the PDF. Integrating is fast.)

Comment: @BoristheSpider the equivalent for coin flips would be a binomial distribution, which tells me the odds of seeing *k* heads in *n* flips, and can be used to approximate the results of flipping coins without actually doing so.

Comment: This is a really cool question! BTW, it might be worth asking this on math stack overflow.

Comment: I posted an exact solution to computing the probability distribution, if anyone's interested, along with some Java code for executing it. It's quite inefficient, and can't come close to the numbers I want to compute, but it was a fun coding exercise nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a way of solving this, and finally got around to writing it up in Java. This gives an exact solution for computing the probability of `m` ships not being hit given `k` ships and `n` shots. It is, however, quite computationally expensive. First, a summary of what I did:

The proability is equal to the total number of ways to shoot the ships with exactly `m` not hit divided by the total number of ways to shoot ships.

```
P = m_misses / total
```

Total is `k^n`, since each shot can hit one of `k` ships.

To get the numerator, start with `nCr(k,m)`. This is the number of ways of choosing `m` ships to not be hit. This multiplied by the number of ways of hitting `k-m` ships without missing any is the total probability.

```
     nCr(k,m)*(k-m_noMiss)
 P = ---------------------
             k^n
```

Now to calculate the second term in the numerator. This is the sum across all distributions of shots of how many ways there are for a certain shot distribution to happen. For example, if 2 ships are hit by 3 bullets, and each ship is hit at least once, they can be hit in the following ways:

```
100
010
001
110
101
011
```

The shot distributions are equal to the length k-m compositions of k. In this case, we would have [2,1] and [1,2], the length 2 compositions of 3.

For the first composition, [2,1], we can calculate the numbers of ways of generating this by choosing 2 out of the 3 shots to hit the first ship, and then 1 out of the remaining 1 shots to hit the second, i.e. `nCr(3,2) * nCr(1,1)`. Note that we can simplify this to `3!/(2!*1!)`. This pattern applies to all shot patters, so the number of ways that a certain pattern, `p`, can occur can be written as `n!/prodSum(j=1,k-m,p_j!)`, in which the notation indicates the product sum from 1 to `k-m`, `j` is an index, and `p_j` represents the `j`th term in `p`.

If we define `P` as the set of all length `k-m` compositions of `n`, the probability of `m` ships not being hit is then:

```
     nCr(k,m)*sum(p is an element of P, n!/prodSum(j=1,k-m,p_j!))
 P = --------------------------------------------------------------
                                 k^n
```

The notation is a bit sloppy since there's not way of putting equations of math symbols into SO, but that's the gist of it.

That being said, this method is horribly inefficient, but I can't seem to find a better one. If someone can simplify this, by all means post your method! I'm curious as to how it can be done.

And the java code for doing this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils;

class Prob{
    public boolean listsEqual(Integer[] integers, Integer[] rootComp){
        if(integers.length != rootComp.length){
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++){
            if(integers[i] != rootComp[i]){return false;};
        }       
        return true;
    }

    public Integer[] firstComp(int base, int length){
        Integer[] comp = new Integer[length];
        Arrays.fill(comp, 1);
        comp[0] = base - length + 1;
        return comp;        
    }

    public Integer[][] enumerateComps(int base, int length){
        //Provides all compositions of base of size length

        if(length > base){return null;};
        Integer[] rootComp = firstComp(base, length);
        ArrayList<Integer[]> compsArray = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

        do {
            compsArray.add(rootComp);
            rootComp = makeNextComp(rootComp);
        } while(!listsEqual(compsArray.get(compsArray.size() - 1), rootComp));

        Integer[][] newArray = new Integer[compsArray.size()][length];

        int i = 0;
        for (Integer[] comp : compsArray){
            newArray[i] = comp;
            i++;
        }

        return newArray;
    }

    public double getProb(int k, int n, int m){
        //k = # of bins
        //n = number of objects
        //m = number of empty bins

        //First generate list of length k-m compositions of n

        if((n < (k-m)) || (m >= k)){
            return 0;
        }

        int[] comp = new int[n-1];

        Arrays.fill(comp, 1);

        comp[0] = n - (k-m) + 1;

        //Comp is now the first 
        Integer[][] L = enumerateComps(n, k-m);

        double num = 0;
        double den = Math.pow(k, n);
        double prodSum;
        int remainder;

        for(Integer[] thisComp : L){
            remainder = n;
            prodSum = 1;
            for(Integer thisVal : thisComp){
                prodSum = prodSum * ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficient(remainder, thisVal);

                remainder -= thisVal;
            }

            num += prodSum;
        }

        return num * ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficient(k, m) / den;
    }

    public Integer[] makeNextComp(Integer[] rootComp){
        Integer[] comp = rootComp.clone();

        int i = comp.length - 1;
        int lastVal = comp[i];
        i--;

        for(; i >=0 ; i--){
            if (comp[i] != 1){
                //Subtract 1 from comp[i]
                comp[i] -= 1;
                i++;
                comp[i] = lastVal + 1;
                i++;
                for(;i < comp.length; i++){
                    comp[i] = 1;
                };
                return comp;                
            }
        }
        return comp;
    }
}


public class numbersTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //System.out.println(ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficient(100,50));
        Prob getProbs = new Prob();

        Integer k = 10; //ships
        Integer n = 10; //shots
        Integer m = 4; //unscathed

        double myProb = getProbs.getProb(k,n,m);

        System.out.printf("Probability of %s ships,  %s hits, and %s unscathed: %s",k,n,m,myProb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), constraining it to the case where all *p<sub>i</sub>* are equal to *1/k* (be careful to note that the Wikipedia article swaps the meaning of your *k* and *n*).

---

#### Previous attempt at answer

Maybe an approach like the following will be fruitful:

1. the probability that *a particular ship* is hit by a particular shot is *1/n*;
2. the probability that a given ship is hit exactly once after k shots: *h<sub>1</sub> = 1/n (1-1/n)<sup>k-1</sup>*;
3. as above, but exactly twice: *h<sub>2</sub> = (1/n)<sup>2</sup> (1-1/n)<sup>k-2</sup>*, and so on;
4. expected number of ships hit exactly once: *n h<sub>1</sub>* and so on.

Comment: And if we assume, that the ship hit by a shot is chosen uniformly random, than the distribution of hits is binomial - P(number of hits on a specific is i) = binom(k,i) * (1/n)^i * (1-1/n)^(k-i)

Comment: still missing the binomial term!

Comment: Substituting (2) into (4), this would give the expected number of ships hit exactly once as *n*(1/n)*(1-1/n)^(k-1) = (1-1/n)^(k-1)*, which is always less than one, and hence doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ckersch We should invert this problem and pose it as *the expected number of repeats in a combination*.

Comment: The number of shots on one ship is binomial, but the probabilities aren't independent, so I can't quite generalize it. For example, if I have five shots, and the first ship is hit five times, the probability of the rest being hit at all is zero.

Comment: @ckersch an expected value below one makes sense, but you are right, the expression is wrong

Comment: @ckersch, yes, this is true. We are speaking of two different distributions here - the distribution of number of shots hitting a ship, and the distribution of the distribution of number of ships hit by different number of shots.

Comment: @ckersch If you see this as pulling a ball *k* times out of a sack with *n* balls, then you are taking into account the dependence. So you have a combination with repeats.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That holds true if I'm trying to figure out how many times I pulled one ball out, but not if I'm trying to figure out how many balls I pulled out twice.

Comment: @ckersch You are interested in the *expected number of m-repeats* in an average combination, with *m* ranging from 0 to *k*.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Or, more specifically, the distribution of the number of m-repeats, with m ranging from 0 to k, though in practice I don't need to go all the way up to k, since the probability that the number is greater than one will become negligible well before that.

Comment: Well, I think what you are really interested in is the (k+1)-dimensional distribution of the numbers of these m-repeats simultaneously for all k values. For example, if n=2 and k=3, than the question is, what is the probability of the possible outcome (number of 0-times-hit ships=1, number of 1-time-hit ships=0, number of 2-time-hit ships=0, and number of 3-time-hit ships=1), and the probability of the only other outcome (number of 0-times-hit ships=0, number of 1-time-hit ships=1, number of 2-time-hit ships=1, and number of 3-time-hit ships=0). Do I get it correctly?

Comment: @elias yes, but that seemed like it would be very complicated, so I'm fine with slightly fudging it and computing 0 hit ships, 1 hit ships, and 2 hit ships seperately, so long as the distribution looks about the same.

Comment: @ckersch if you want to compute these marginal distributions, you do not take into consideration the dependency of the related random variables, i.e. the sum is not guaranteed to be the value you want to be

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that each shot has probability h to hit any bad ship.  If h = 0, all shots will miss.  If h = 1, all shots will hit *something*.

Now, let's say you shoot b bullets.  The expected value of ships hit is simply Hs = h * b, but these are not *unique* ships hit.

So we have a list of ships that is Hs long.  The chance of any specific enemy ship being hit given N enemy ships is 1/N.  Therefore, the chance to be in the first k slots but no the other slots is

```
(1/N)^k * (1-1/N)^(Hs-k)
```

Note that this is Marko Topolnik's answer.  The problem is that this is a specific ship being in the FIRST k slots, as opposed to being in any combination of k slots.  We must modify this by taking into the account the number of combinations of k slots in Hs total slots:

```
(Hs choose k) * (1/N)^k * (1-1/N)^(Hs-k)
```

Now we have the chance of a specific ship being in k slots.  Well, now we need to consider the entire fleet of N ships:

```
(Hs choose k) * (1/N)^k * (1-1/N)^(Hs-k) * N
```

This expression represents the expected number of ships being hit k times within an N sized fleet that was hit with Hs shots in a uniform distribution.

**Numerical Sanity Check:**

Let's say two bullets hit (Hs=2) and we have two enemy ships (N=2).  Assign each ship a binary ID, and let's enumerate the possible hit lists.

```
00 (ship 0 hit twice)
01
10
11
```

The number of ships hit once is:

```
(2 choose 1) * (1/2)^1 * (1-1/2)^(2-1) * 2 = 1
```

The number of ships hit twice is:

```
(2 choose 2) * (1/2)^2 * (1-1/2)^(2-2) * 2 = 0.5
```

To complete the sanity check, we need to make sure our total number of hits equals Hs.  Every ship hit twice takes 2 bullets, and every ship hit once takes one bullet:

```
1*1 + 0.5*2 = 2 == Hs  **TRUE**
```

One more quick example with Hs=3 and N=2:

```
(3 choose 1) * (1/2)^1 * (1-1/2)^(3-1) * 2
3 * 0.5 * 0.25 * 2 = 0.75

(3 choose 2) * (1/2)^2 * (1-1/2)^(3-2) * 2
3 * 0.5^2 * 0.5 * 2 = 0.75

(3 choose 3) * (1/2)^3 * (1-1/2)^(3-3) * 2
1 * 0.5^3 * 1 * 2 = 0.25

0.75 + 0.75*2 + 0.25*3 = 3 == Hs  **TRUE**
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have S ships and fire A shots at them, each individual ship's number of hits will follow a binominal distribution where p = 1/S and n = A:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

You can query this distribution and ask:

- How likely is it for a ship to be hit 0 times?
- How likely is it for a ship to be hit 1 time?
- How likely is it for a ship to be hit 2 times?
- How likely is it for a ship to be hit (max health) or more times? (Hint: Just subtract 1.0 from everything below)

and multiply these by the number of ships, S, to get the number of ships that you expect to be hit 0, 1, 2, 3, etc times. However, as this is an expectation not a randomly rolled result, battles will go exactly the same way every time.

If you have a low number of ships yet high number of shots, you can roll the binominal distribution once per ship. OR if you have a low number of shots yet high number of ships, you can randomly place each shot. I haven't yet thought of a cool way to get the random distribution (or a random approximation thereof) of high number of shots AND high number of shots, but it would be awesome to find out one :)